# Payerid is not returned in Express Checkout GetExpressCheckoutDetails

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

Im currently using Sandbox.
I have returned a token from SetExpressCheckout and using this in GetExpressCheckoutDetails I have returned ACK=success here too, but no Payerid was included in the return parameters.

When I did the redirect using the returned url from SetExpressCheckout, I got to a paypal page saying the transaction had timed out. Should I have expected this or should I somehow sign into paypal sandbox as the buyer to approve the transaction. Not sure how this works in sandbox.

Comment: Can you please post the response of GetExpressCheckoutDetails, hiding all the sensitive information? BTW, you need to do DoExpressCheckoutPayment call to complete the transaction...

Comment: My problem was I was not calling sandbox but live. It works now.